# OrderBy an list in a task function async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, orleans

Okay i am working with orleans and all i really want to do is sort an list after a value in state. i try to this by doing this

```
public async Task SortEntries()
    {
         State.Entries.OrderBy(GetComparator);
    }

    private async decimal GetComparator(IEntryGrain x)
    {
        var a = await x.GetState();

        return Task.FromResult(a);
    }
```

but this got two wrongs in them that i am trying to solve. first of the Task SortEntries task lacks an await operator which i guess might still work the problem is that GetComparator says an async method must be void, Task or Task.The most neat way i first thought would be to do all the sorting in SortEntries like this

```
State.Entries.OrderBy((x) => x.GetState().Result.TotalPoints);
```

But the GetState() need to be async with an await but i cant do that on the orderBy or sort. Anyone who can push me in the right direction or encountered something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) `OrderBy` doesn't work with async/await. A qiuck fix would be to use the Result property of GetState in GetComparator

```
private decimal GetComparator(IEntryGrain x)
{
    var task = x.GetState();
    task.Wait();

    if(task.IsFaulted)
        throw new Exception($"could not get the state: {task.Exception}", task.Exception);

    return task.Result;
}
```

2.) `OrderBy` return only an `IEnumerable`, so it wont be ordered there. Need to enumerate it once to execute the order by. And you need to return the result because `OrderBy` only returns a ordered list, but does not order the list itself.

```
public IList<IEntryGrain> SortEntries()
{
     return State.Entries.OrderBy(GetComparator)
                         .ToList();
}
```

or write it back to the property if it is writable and thread safe

```
public void SortEntries()
{
     State.Entries = State.Entries.OrderBy(GetComparator)
                                  .ToList();
}
```

---

So you get:

```
public IList<IEntryGrain> SortEntries()
{
    return State.Entries.OrderBy(GetComparator)
                        .ToList();
}

private decimal GetComparator(IEntryGrain x)
{
    var task = x.GetState();
    task.Wait();

    if(task.IsFaulted)
        throw new Exception($"could not get the state: {task.Exception}", task.Exception);

    return task.Result;
}
```

Comment: `State.Entries.OrderBy(async (x) => await GetComparator(x));` and `State.Entries.OrderBy(GetComparator);` behave *identially* other than the fact that your version allocates more objects and takes more time.  Other than the reduced performance, there's no observable difference between the two.  Additionally your second and final methods don't compile at all, because you're returning a type that the compiler is not expecting to be returned for those methods.

Comment: Now you're just synchronously blocking on asynchronous operations and that's going to just deadlock, and not do the work asynchronously, which is the whole point of having asynchronous operations here in the first place.

Comment: It will kill Orleans scheduler, never use blocking calls in Orleans! I would prefer to rethink the whole problem. Do you really want to call another grain for each comparison during each sort? It will kill the performance even without the blocking call: entry grains will be loaded into memory from DB, usually on other nodes, etc. If the Entries are some references to grains, cache the values used for comparison. But do you really need grains for the entries at all? Or just POCOs? Are the entries DDD/aggregate roots?

Comment: Converting the async method to sync is a bad idea, as @Servy has suggested, you shall just use plain Async